# Opa: Passing Variables to Event Handlers within Iterations

Tags: event-handling, iteration, opa

To Opa Folks out there, I have been puzzled by this issue all of this past weekend.

What I am trying to do in my View, is Iterate through a DBSet returned by my Model data call, generating an XHTML table of records, with each  bound to a click event handler. 
I want this click event handler to accept a property of the iterated record type as an argument, or the record itself. `type team = { string team_id, ...etc}` 
I have a form in my view, where I want to populate the inputs with the values of the most recently clicked table row, which is what the event handler does --- if I can even get the right parameters passed to it.

How do I go about this?

I am trying to get a bit of XHTML to bind a event handler like this

```
<tr onclick={ otherExposedFunctionIWantToCall(team) }>
```

or

```
<tr onclick={ otherExposedFunctionIWantToCall(team.team_id) }>
```

One of the latest things I have resorted to doing, is trying to see if I could access the team_id property I have set on my custom type, team.

```
function teams_management_view(){
    tbody = Iter.fold(
          function(team, acc){
            <>{acc}<tr onclick={ function(_){ Log.info("click", {team.team_id})}}><td class="team_id">{team.team_id}</td><td class="team_name">{team.name}</td></tr></>
          },
          TeamModel.get_teams(),
          <></>
        )
  ...
}
```

None of those forms of those event handlers were able to compile when I used them in my iteration code.

Why does this not work?
Is the problem that I am iterating with dynamic records?
Can I even bind such a function to an event?
Do Opa Client-side events have any way to access the target of an event - didn't seem to find any?
What are my options for achieving my goal?

If anyone can help me understand any part of this question, I would be much obliged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, turns out I was completely blanking out on the fact that the team variable is perfectly within the function's scope (that is passed to the Iterator).

Turned out that I was not casting team_id, which is an int field, as a string...

I found out this works:

```
<tr onclick={ function(_){ setTeamView("{team.team_id}")} }>
```

Whereas, this kept giving me an error from before,

```
Expression has type
    void
    but is coerced into
    FunAction.t

<tr onclick={ setTeamView("{team.team_id}")}>
```

Your custom functions are best wrapped up in an anonymous wrapper function first, as evident in the first example I gave. The string casting of team.team_id only worked in the first case.

On to the next one I guess!